# Inserting data from android in cassandra

Tags: android, cassandra

I am working on a POC on cassandra. What I want is to insert data from android application to Cassandra (latitude, longitude, phone number, and other things). Then I will use this data on another application to track a used in real time that has that android application installed. I need suggestions for the best approach to do this.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd head over here https://academy.datastax.com/ and learn the basics of Cassandra - especially the data modeling.

Once you've figured out your data models, you can easily use the Java driver (assuming you're using ADK/Android Studio) to write data from Android to Cassandra.

That being said, depending on how many clients you're expecting, it might be worth also investing in a message queue such as Kafka or Amazon SQS since Android apps have a tendency to explode in growth without warning.